# Django Social Authentication Create New User With Custom Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm trying to develop a Facebook social authentication feature on an application that uses a custom Django user model and django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 as the social authentication package. My custom user model is called 'Account' and it inherits from the AbstractBaseUser class. The Account model is shown below:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  # Account model fields: 
  email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
  last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  # The user will log in with their email instead of username:
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

  # Required fields when registering, other than the email:
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

  # Telling the Account object how to use the account manager:
  objects = MyAccountManager()
```

The function that handles creating a new user is called 'create_user' and is defined within my custom written MyAccountManager class which extends the Django BaseUserManager class. This is given below:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None):
    # Checking to see if correct function parameters have been passed in: 
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
    if not first_name:
        raise ValueError('Users must have a first name')
    if not last_name:
        raise ValueError('Users must have a last name')

    # Creating the new user:
    user = self.model(
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
        username = username,
        first_name = first_name,
        last_name = last_name,
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using = self._db)
    
    return user
```

I've set up a working django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 url for creating a new user with a Facebook account. The relevant Facebook configuration in the Django settings.py file is shown below:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = config('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY')
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = config('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET')

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = { 'fields': 'id, name, email' }
```

**The issue that I've been having is the following:**
When the create_user function is called for a user that is using Facebook social login, the parameters email, first_name and last_name, that are required in the create_user function are not being provided by Facebook and I'm getting the error message shown in the image. The error message states the following:

create_user() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first_name' and 'last_name'

[Error Message from Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L32a4.png)

**Does anyone know how I would be able to access these additional parameters (email, first name, last name) from Facebook so that the correct parameters are passed into the create_user function?**

---

**Further Information**

On implementing the pipeline suggestion I am still left with the same issue whereby the custom create_user function is missing both the first_name and last_name parameters. I think the reason that this occurring is due to the suggested pipeline cleanup_social_account function being called after create_user, where in my case both first_name and last_name are required fields, and as such a user object cannot be created in the database if they are not provided at the time the create_user function is called.

I am receiving this error due to the following function in the suggested custom pipeline:

```
social_core.pipeline.user.create_user
```

The code for this function in the social_core installed library is the following:

```
def create_user(strategy, details, backend, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
  if user:
      return {'is_new': False}

  fields = dict((name, kwargs.get(name, details.get(name)))
                for name in backend.setting('USER_FIELDS', USER_FIELDS))
  if not fields:
      return

  return {
      'is_new': True,
      'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
  }
```

The details parameter passed into the above function contains the values that I need (first_name and last_name). However, they are not actually being added into the fields variable when it is created. The fields variable is shown above and is defined by the following:

```
fields = dict((name, kwargs.get(name, details.get(name)))
                for name in backend.setting('USER_FIELDS', USER_FIELDS))
```

**In summary:**
The issue appears to be that first_name and last_name are not appearing within backend.settings('USER_FIELDS', USER_FIELDS), and therefore are not being added to the fields variable, and as such are not being passed into strategy.create_user(**fields).

Comment: Have you tried just adding them to the list of extra_params?  Also, in case you need a reference, here is the API field reference.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: Thanks for the reference link, I've just added those extra parameters in my settings.py file as shown below. However, I'm still unsure as to how those parameters can be accessed and passed into the create_user function in my extension of the BaseUserManager.

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = { 'fields': 'id, email, first_name, last_name' }

Comment: I posted code below that can help.  But after posting, I realized that it may be you are just missing some of the pipelines to add the extra data.

Comment: Just tried implementing your suggestion however I'm still getting the same error. I've added some further information to the question to shown what I think is the reason for this error. In short, it seems that this is occurring because both first_name and last_name are not defined in `backend.setting('USER_FIELDS', USER_FIELDS))`

Comment: I'm at a loss for a solution.  I can just add one further point.  Facebook can be dumb sometimes.  Just yesterday, my social auth login stopped returning the email address for Facebook, so I had to create a custom create_user pipeline function to validate that Facebook returned it first.  You may just need to overwrite one of the pipelines.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: No worries Matt, thanks for the help. I'll do some more research on custom pipelines and see if i can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

So social_auth auto-populates those fields for me when I just get name and email from Facebook.  It knows to bring in first_name and last_name.  Since it doesn't seem to be working for you, you can create a custom pipeline function.

settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',

# YOUR CUSTOM PIPELINE FUNCTION HERE.  I CREATED A FILE/MODULE
# NAMED pipeline.py AND STUCK IT IN THERE.  MAKE SURE TO PUT THIS
# AFTER CREATE USER.
'path.to.custom.pipeline.cleanup_social_account',

'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
```

)

pipeline.py:

```
def cleanup_social_account(backend, uid, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
"""
3rd party: python-social-auth.

Social auth pipeline to cleanup the user's data.  Must be placed
after 'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user'.
"""

# Check if the user object exists and a new account was just created.
if user and kwargs.get('is_new', False):

    *** THIS IS UNTESTED, BUT FACEBOOK'S DATA SHOULD COME INTO THE DETAILS KWARG ***
    user.first_name = kwargs['details']['first_name']
    user.last_name = kwargs['details']['last_name']
    user.save()

return {'user': user}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USER_FIELDS = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']` in your `settings.py` file and these fields should be added to `**kwargs` in you `create_user` method.

### Sample Usage

##### In settings.py file add this

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USER_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

##### In your UserManager class modify create_user like below

```
def create_user(self, password=None, **kwargs):
    """Create and return a `User` with an email, username and password."""

    first_name = kwargs.get('first_name')
    last_name = kwargs.get('last_name')
    email = kwargs.get('email')

    if first_name is None or last_name is None:
        raise TypeError(f"Invalid FirstName: {first_name}, LastName: {last_name}, Email: {email}")

    if email is None:
        raise TypeError("Users must have an email address.")

    user = self.model(
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()

    return user
```